# Reply tweets - set in_reply_to_in using twitter_oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am not able to reply to tweets usign twitter_oauth.
Here is my code

```
 @twitter_client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
          :consumer_key => 'key ',
          :consumer_secret => 'secret',
          :token => token, 
          :secret => secret
        )
        response = @twitter_client.update(response_description, {"in_reply_to_status_id" => tweet_id})
    logger.info response.inspect
```

It posts the tweet but not as a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. You need to include the twitter username of the tweet to which you are replying.

> Note:: This parameter will be ignored unless the author of the tweet this parameter references is mentioned within the status text. Therefore, you must include @username, where username is the author of the referenced tweet, within the update.

Found this at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update stated in relation to in_reply_to_status_id param.